# Magento Quick View Cart - Content of Cart Product name formar gone Wrong

Tags: product, cart, format

Anyone have a clue why is this Product name in top right ajax cart quick view LIKE THIS as you can see on the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, Because **the product name has no space(s) in between and it's a one long word**

**Update**
Check the links below for your reference

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307668/css-or-what-forcing-the-text-split-into-multiple-lines

http://code.webplatform.org/gist/5888667

https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/

Comment: Hi, there is a space between words in product name of course. But I'll take a look at your reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It turned out to be a CSS issue. A themes CSS class name minicartInner was set to 300px width. After increase to 600px for a test, the product name showed up normal in one line, letter after letter.